# CompactMap to filter objects that have nil properties

Tags: arrays, swift, collections

How do I filter out possible nil values in properties with a compactMap so I don't have to forecast a nil property to return the object.

Currently I have

```
let objects: [Object] = anotherObject.array.compactMap ({
                        return Object(property: $0.property!)
 })
```

What I would like is some guard staetment or option to filter out these objects that may have a property that could be nil. For example if $0.property is nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can still use `Array.compactMap`

With if-statement

```
anotherObject.array.compactMap { object in
    if let property = object.property {
        return Object(property: property)
    }
    return nil
}
```

With guard statement

```
anotherObject.array.compactMap {
    guard let property = $0.property else { return nil }

    return Object(property: property)
}
```

ternary operator example

```
anotherObject.array.compactMap { object in
    object.property == nil ? nil : Object(property: object.property!)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You could do this :

```
let objects: [Object] = anotherObject.array.compactMap {
    return $0.property == nil ? nil : $0
}
```

Or use `filter`:

```
let objects: [Object] = anotherObject.array.filter { $0.property != nil }
```